# New column in a pandas Dataframe based on a the index of minimum value of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For data analysis need (more than 500 000 records), I need to do the following :

As an example, let's say than I have the following array :

```
RMI=[ 100, 200 ,300, 400 ]
```

and the following dataframe :

```
ar = numpy.array([[-2.0, 2.0, -5, 0], [2.7, 10, 5.4, 7], [5.3, 9, 1.5, -12]])
df = pandas.DataFrame(ar, index = ['1', '2', '3'], columns = ['Seed1', 'Seed2', 'Seed3', 'Seed4'])
```

I need a new column `RMI_number` in `df`, that contains the value in RMI whose index corresponds to the min value between Seed1,Seed2,Seed3,Seed4.

In my example, I expect to have

```
df['RMI_number']=[300, 100, 400]
```

300 because the minimum value for first line is in third position (-5 value)
100 becasue the minimum value for second line is in first position (2.7)
400 because the minium value for third line is in fourth position (-12)

What would be the most efficient way to do that ?
I've tried a lot of option base on `idxmin`, or `groupby` but didn't get what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html):

```
df['RMI_number'] = np.array(RMI)[np.argmin(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)]
```

Or, if you have other columns:

```
df['RMI_number'] = np.array(RMI)[np.argmin(df.filter(like='Seed').to_numpy(), axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   Seed1  Seed2  Seed3  Seed4  RMI_number
1   -2.0    2.0   -5.0    0.0         300
2    2.7   10.0    5.4    7.0         100
3    5.3    9.0    1.5  -12.0         400
```

Answer (score 1):

Another short version of using `np.argmin` on dataframe values:

```
np.array(RMI)[df.values.argmin(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `idxmin` along rows and then extract the "Seed" name as required:

```
df["RMI_number"] = df.idxmin(axis=1).str.lstrip("Seed").astype(int).mul(100)
```

Alternatively, transpose and reset_index() to reset the column names and then use `idxmin`:

```
df["RMI_number"] = df.T.reset_index(drop=True).idxmin().add(1).mul(100)

>>> df
   Seed1  Seed2  Seed3  Seed4  RMI_number
1   -2.0    2.0   -5.0    0.0         300
2    2.7   10.0    5.4    7.0         100
3    5.3    9.0    1.5  -12.0         400
```